# How to Consume REST Api and then Display Top Stories as JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot

**GOAL:** Create a Spring Boot Project to consume a public API for NY Times to display the Top Stories at the moment.

**What I have done:** I have consumed the REST Api and stored my response into a jsonObject. I have trying the pass the two unit tests, but unable to pass the first junit test. Pretty sure what I am doing is incorrect even though I am passing the second junit test.

**News POJO**

```
public class News {

private String title;
private String section;

// GETTER & SETTER

}
```

**News Service Class**

```
@Service public class NewsService {

private String apiKey = "gIIWu7P82GBslJAd0MUSbKMrOaqHjWOo";

public News getTopStories() throws Exception {


    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    News news = new News();

    String getUrl = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/science.json?api-key=" + apiKey;

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<Map> newsList = restTemplate.exchange(getUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Map.class);
    JSONObject jsonObject;

    if (newsList.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {

        jsonObject = new JSONObject(newsList.getBody());
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            news.setTitle(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("title").toString());
            news.setSection(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("section").toString());

        }
    }
    // this is only returning the last index of the jsonArray (pretty sure I am suppose to return all to in my URL). Can't seem to come up with the logic to do that.
    return news; 
}

}
```

**News Controller Class**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class NewsController {

@Autowired
NewsService newsService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/news/topstories", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public News getNews() throws Exception {
    return newsService.getTopStories();
}

}
```

**JUnit Test Needing to Pass**

```
@Test
public void retrievetest_ok() throws Exception {

     mockMvc.perform(get("/api/news/topstories" )).andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.results.[0].title").exists())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.section").exists());


}

@Test public void Newstest_ok() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/api/news/topstories" ))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.title").exists())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.section").exists());
}


}
```

**Error I receive for first JUnit Test**

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
  HTTP Method = GET
  Request URI = /api/news/topstories
   Parameters = {}
      Headers = {}

Handler:
         Type = com.example.project.NewsController
       Method = public com.example.project.News com.example.project.NewsController.getNews() throws java.lang.Exception

Async:
  Async started = false
  Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
         Type = null

ModelAndView:
    View name = null
         View = null
        Model = null

FlashMap:
   Attributes = null


 MockHttpServletResponse:
       Status = 200
 Error message = null
      Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
 Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
         Body = {"title":"Shrinking and Quaking Hint at Moon’s Tectonic Life","section":"Science"}
Forwarded URL = null
Redirected URL = null
      Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.results.[0].title", exception: Missing property in path $['results']
...
...
...
...
```

Comment: Just return a list of `News`

Comment: You override `news` object in the loop (for ...). Create a list of `News`, fill it in loop and return it.

Comment: Changed method return type to List<News>. Declared List<News> topStories. I did news.setTitle and news.setSection and then added news to  List<News>. This is the error I received on the second JUnit Test 

"java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.title", exception: Expected to find an object with property ['title'] in path $ but found 'net.minidev.json.JSONArray'"

Comment: @NickSmith - how did you solve it? I am walking in the same shoes and facing the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new object for each top story

```
public List<News> getTopStories() throws Exception {

    List<News> topStories = new ArrayList<>();
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    String getUrl = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/science.json?api-key=" + apiKey;

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<Map> newsList = restTemplate.exchange(getUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Map.class);
    JSONObject jsonObject;

    if (newsList.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {

        jsonObject = new JSONObject(newsList.getBody());
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            News news = new News();
            news.setTitle(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("title").toString());
            news.setSection(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("section").toString());
            topStories.add(news);
        }
    }
    // this is only returning the last index of the jsonArray (pretty sure I am suppose to return all to in my URL). Can't seem to come up with the logic to do that.
    return topStories; 
}
```

And also your controller and tests should be adapted to deal with list result.

Comment: I did that and got the following error---------> java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.results.[0].title", exception: Expected to find an object with property ['results'] in path $ but found 'net.minidev.json.JSONArray'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.

Comment: @NickSmith Absolutely you should not have `['results']`. Because you test your rest controller not the news api. Your result controller has a list of `News` object. So the test should be against `$[0]` which is a `News`

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but unclear as to what I have to do to pass my JUNIT Test. I cannot edit my JUNIT test. I have to pass them as they are. Thank you for all your help, I truly appreciate you taking your timing to help me.

Comment: @NickSmith The tests are wrong so. In second test you want to test `topStories` endpoint. It returns a collection but in test body you deal with that as a `News` instance

Comment: @NickSmith Or in first test, you test result of endpoint with two approach. First you expect the result of endpoint has a member named `results` which is a collection and another member which is a string (of `News` type).

Comment: @NickSmith If you want to pass current tests you need to add a collection member named `results` to `News` class which is `List<News>`. It's like linked news

Comment: I tried adding the List<News> as private variable to my POJO. But I think I did it wrong. Do you mind showing me how? I also called setter method for it after my for loop and added my entire list to it.

Comment: @NickSmith As I said your tests are wrong. You need to change them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193604/discussion-between-ebrahim-pasbani-and-nick-smith).

Answer (score 3):

The POJO needs to be updated to pass all the test cases.

```
public class News{
    private String section;
    private Results[] results;
    private String title;


    public Results[] getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(Results[] results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    public String getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public void setSection(String section) {
        this.section = section;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

Then You need to add one more POJO Class called Result

```
public class Results{
    private String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

And finally the service Class

```
public News getTopStories()
    {
        List<News> topStories = new ArrayList<>();
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String getUrl = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/science.json?api-key=<your-api-key>";
        News news=new News();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<Map> newsList = restTemplate.exchange(getUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Map.class);
        JSONObject jsonObject;

        if (newsList.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {

            jsonObject = new JSONObject(newsList.getBody());
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            Results[] results = new Results[jsonArray.length()];
            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                news.setTitle(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("title").toString());
                news.setSection(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("section").toString());
                String title=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("title").toString();
                results[i]=new Results();
                results[i].setTitle(title);
                news.setResults(results);
                topStories.add(news);
            }

        }
        return topStories.get(0); 
    }
```

This will surely work for all the JUnit you mentioned.
Or you can even create inner class Result instead of creating a new POJO file.

Answer (score 1):

For the specific tests you need to create a result class in **News.java** itself.

```
import java.util.List;

class Results{
    private String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}


public class News {
private String title;
private String section;
private Results[] results;

public Results[] getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(Results[] results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getSection() {
    return section;
}
public void setSection(String section) {
    this.section = section;
}

}
```

And then in your **News Service class**

```
@Service
public class NewsService {

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
   return builder.build();
}

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

private String apiKey = "<---Your_Key--->";

    public News getTopStories() {
     List<News> topStories = new ArrayList<>();

    String getUrl = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/science.json?api-key=" + apiKey;

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<Map> newsList = restTemplate.exchange(getUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Map.class);
    JSONObject jsonObject;

    if (newsList.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {

        jsonObject = new JSONObject(newsList.getBody());
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
        Results[] results = new Results[jsonArray.length()];

        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            News news = new News();
            news.setTitle(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("title").toString());
            news.setSection(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("section").toString());
            String title=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("title").toString();
            results[i]=new Results();
            results[i].setTitle(title);
            news.setResults(results);
            topStories.add(news);
        }
    }
    return topStories.get(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The POJO needs to be updated to pass all the test cases.

```
public class News{
    private String section;
    private Results[] results;
    private String title;


    public Results[] getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(Results[] results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    public String getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public void setSection(String section) {
        this.section = section;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

Then You need to add one more POJO Class called Result

```
public class Results{
    private String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

And finally the service Class

```
public News getTopStories()
    {
        List<News> topStories = new ArrayList<>();
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String getUrl = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/science.json?api-key=<your-api-key>";
        

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<Map> newsList = restTemplate.exchange(getUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Map.class);
        JSONObject jsonObject;

        if (newsList.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            News news=new News();
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(newsList.getBody());
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            Results[] results = new Results[jsonArray.length()];
            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                news.setTitle(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("title").toString());
                news.setSection(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("section").toString());
                String title=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("title").toString();
                results[i]=new Results();
                results[i].setTitle(title);
                news.setResults(results);
                topStories.add(news);
            }

        }
        return topStories.get(0); 
    }
```

INSTEAD OF CREATING NEWS OBJECT ONCE OUTSIDE THE FOR LOOP CREATE IT EVER TIME IN FORLOOP.